# typing a certain word on a webpage to go to another webpage

Tags: javascript, keyboard, event-listener

what I have in mind is that when the user type "password" on a screen (with no input field, just an image),
then it will direct them to another page (such as login page or etc).

I think I will have to use an eventlistener for keyboard.

if "password" is pressed down with keyboard the the browser direct to another page.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

What I do is record each keypress and append each pressed key to the string "typed_word".
If the string becomes "password" you perform the redirect.

```
<script>
    typed_word=""
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
        typed_word=typed_word+event.key
        if (typed_word==="password"){
            window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com")
        }
    })
</script>
```